# If $A$ is Hermitian, then $A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I$ is positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\bar{\sigma}(A)$ is the largest singular value of the Hermitian matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$. How can I show that $A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I$ is positive semi-definite? Here is what I tried so far. $A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $x^\star (A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I) x \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb C^n - \{\mathbf 0\}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
x^\star (A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I) x &= x^\star A x + x^\star\bar{\sigma}(A)I x \\
&= x^\star Q^\star \Lambda Q x + x^\star\bar{\sigma}(A)I x \\
&= (Qx)^\star \Lambda (Qx) + x^\star\bar{\sigma}(A)I x
\end{align}
At this point, I can show that each of the individual summands are positive semi-definite to show that $A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I$ is positive semi-definite. For example, $\bar{\sigma}(A)I$ is positive semi-definite since $\bar{\sigma}(A)$ is non-negative. However, I am not sure how to show that $\Lambda$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: It might be useful to write $x = \sum_i c_i v_i$ where $v_i$ are a set of eigenvectors of $A$ that form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (why is this possible?). You will probably also need to use the fact that eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices have nice properties.

Comment: Here is a counterexample to your assertion: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$ ($A+\overline\sigma(A)I=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$).

Comment: I do think you need another assumption on $\overline\sigma(A)$ though, what if it is negative? E.g. $A = -I$

Comment: @AnneBauval the maximum singular value of the counter example you mentioned is 2 not 1. The singular values of the A you mentioned are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^\star A$.

Comment: @BaronVT the largest singular value of $A = -I$ is 1 not -1. Therefore, $A + \bar{\sigma}(A)I \geq 0$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hermitian matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. Let $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le\ldots \le \lambda_n$ denote its eigenvalues.  Then the matrix $A-\lambda_1I$ is positive semi-definite. The largest singular value is equal  $$\tilde{\sigma}(A)=\max\{|\lambda_k|\,:\, 1\le k\le n\}=\max\{-\lambda_1,\lambda_n\}$$ In particular $$-\lambda_1\le\tilde{\sigma}(A)$$
Therefore the matrix $$A+ \tilde{\sigma}(A)I=[A-\lambda_1I]+[ \tilde{\sigma}(A)+\lambda_1]I$$ is positive semi-definite as a sum of positive semi-definite matrices.

Comment: How do you show that $A - \lambda_1 I$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: The smallest eigenvalue of $B:=A-\lambda_1I$ is equal $0.$ Thus $$0=\min \{\langle Bx,x\rangle\,:\,\|x\|=1\}$$